# Android ImageButton Resolution Problems

Tags: android, layout, size, resolution, imagebutton

I want to have two buttons at the top of my program taking users to different activities. I'm having a lot of trouble with the formatting.

How can I make it so that the buttons will stretch proportionally based on the screen size? Right now, they will look OK for one screen size, then I will switch to a different one and it will appear all smushed or stretched. I've tried all of the different ScaleTypes and none seem to make a difference. I also went though and proportionally saved all of the images to the correct sizes regardimg  xhdpi, hdpi, etc using [Shubhayu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697440/button-image-size-in-android).

Here's my code so far:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/brushed_metal_background_dark"
tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/incidentsSelect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/incident_bar2"
    android:contentDescription="Incidents"
    android:onClick="chooseIncident"
    android:scaleType="center" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/operationalPeriodsSelect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/operationalperiod_bar2"
    android:contentDescription="Operational Periods"
    android:onClick="chooseOperationalPeriod"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `android:background` to `android:src` that will keep the aspect ratio. Use `android:scaleType="centerInside"` to fit whole image inside button area and optionally use `android:adjustViewBounds=true` to remove empty spaces. Example:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/incidentsSelect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="Incidents"
    android:onClick="chooseIncident"
    android:src="@drawable/incident_bar2"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/operationalPeriodsSelect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="Operational Periods"
    android:onClick="chooseOperationalPeriod"
    android:src="@drawable/operationalperiod_bar2"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I also had to use android:background="@null" to get rid of the icky background border thing.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are trying to size the buttons evenly on the top of the screen. If that's the case then you should set `android:layout_width="0dp"`.

Comment: I'm not having an issue with making them even, it's basically the height that's giving me the problems. I think it's evenly stretching the width, but not the height, so basically if the screen is a little smaller, my buttons are huge and fat and if it is larger, they' get really skinny.

Answer (score 0):

Just use android:layout_width = "wrap_content"