# How to make my image just appear on my button, and not overlap

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-button

I want to just have a button where the image will be the background, instead of loading the button to be the images. For example, no matter what size the image is, I still want the button to stay the same size. I tried to edit my image to be the same size, but the nice rounded corners are now gone and I don't have the software to put corners on an image accurately.

Do I just have a different understanding of what background means? I would think that It would draw the button and then put the image as the background instead of draw the button, then re-draw the button to be the same size as the background image.

Below is the xml code for my button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/newUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSize"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:text="New User"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
    tools:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

The line in question is the `android:background="@drawable/ButtonSize"` and my file ButtonSize.png is a 90x50 pixel image that would fit really nicely onto an Button.

My question is: Is there any other way to set the image purely as a background in a literal sense, where I could also, for example, add curved edges using `android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"`, ect.

Comment: There is a button that can use Image as the background called ImageButton. Instead of using normal Button and set background with @drawable, use Image Button. more info refer here, 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Button you can use Image button and set the following property will give the image to Entire Button.

```
android:scaleType="centerInside" 
android:adjustViewBounds=true
```

For more reference visit the following link[Android ImageButton Resolution Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904465/android-imagebutton-resolution-problems)

Hope It will help you