# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, xml

This my game everything is working fine except when loading images as background to my buttons, i have tried all answers in stackoverflow but none worked, the error eliminates when the background image is not set. 
Below are my Codes

**Logcat**

```
 10-30 19:38:42.473 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 16777228 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 5MB until OOM"
    10-30 19:38:42.473 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
    10-30 19:38:42.476 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class <unknown>
    10-30 19:38:42.476 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at com.danaraddi.quickmath.activities.ScoreActivity.onCreate(ScoreActivity.java:56)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class <unknown>
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    10-30 19:38:42.478 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    10-30 19:38:42.483 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    10-30 19:38:42.483 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:    ... 17 more
    10-30 19:38:42.483 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    10-30 19:38:42.483 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    10-30 19:38:42.483 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    10-30 19:38:42.483 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:    ... 26 more
    10-30 19:38:42.483 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 16777228 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 5MB until OOM
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:170)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:115)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1215)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1124)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2630)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3948)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:677)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:109)
    10-30 19:38:42.484 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:105)
    10-30 19:38:42.485 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:101)
    10-30 19:38:42.485 17302-17302/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/System.err:    ... 28 more
    10-30 19:38:42.531 17302-17317/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    10-30 19:38:42.531 17302-17317/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9fbbf0e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    10-30 19:38:42.728 17302-17317/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    10-30 19:38:42.728 17302-17317/com.danaraddi.quickmath W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9fb7b280, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    10-30 19:38:43.227 17302-17317/com.danaraddi.quickmath E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9fb75650
    10-30 19:38:46.073 17302-17317/com.danaraddi.quickmath E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9fb766f0
```

**Layout XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_green"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="4"
    tools:context="com.danaraddi.quickmath.activities.ScoreActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="GAME OVER"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button_normal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_score_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SCORE"
            android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SCORE"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_score_title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_score"
            android:id="@+id/tv_bestscore_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HIGH SCORE"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_bestscore"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_bestscore_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SCORE"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="SHARE"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_return_home"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_home"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_leaderboards"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_game"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_reload"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_reload"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java File**

```
package com.danaraddi.quickmath.activities;



//import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.danaraddi.quickmath.GameServices.LeaderBoardHelper;
import com.danaraddi.quickmath.R;
import com.danaraddi.quickmath.Utility.PreferenceManager;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class ScoreActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
    int BACK_KEY_PRESS_COUNT = 0;
    PreferenceManager preferenceManager;

    // Textview Objects
    @InjectView(R.id.tv_score)
    TextView tvScore;
    @InjectView(R.id.tv_bestscore)
    TextView tvBestScore;


    @OnClick(R.id.btn_reload)
    void btn_reload_click() {
        reloadGame();
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.btn_leaderboards)
    void btn_gameservices_click() {
        googleGameServices();
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.btn_return_home)
    void btn_home_click() {
       returnHome();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // error occuring
        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);
            ButterKnife.inject(this);
            preferenceManager = new PreferenceManager(this);
            setScores();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        returnHome();
    }

    // kill activity
    private void returnHome(){
        this.finish();
    }

    //reload game
    private void reloadGame(){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, GameActivity.class));
        this.finish();

    }

    // Game Services
    private void googleGameServices(){
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(
                        getApiClient(), getString(R.string.quick_math_leaderboard)),
                2);
    }


    private void setScores(){
       tvScore.setText(String.valueOf( preferenceManager.returnFromPreferenceLong("SCORE")));
        tvBestScore.setText(String.valueOf( preferenceManager.returnFromPreferenceLong("HIGHSCORE")));
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        LeaderBoardHelper.submitScore(getApiClient(), preferenceManager.returnFromPreferenceLong("HIGHSCORE"));
    }
}
```

***I have stored , background image in drawable folder, and other images that are used for buttons are even stored in drawable folder, button images are 512 * 512px resolution***

---

> I have fixed this issues, i have reduced the image resolution form
>   512*512 to 96*96 from the guidelines suggested here

*** [Button Image size in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697440/button-image-size-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to allocate a 16,777,228-byte block of memory. You will not have a block of memory that big on many devices, and there will be times when you do not have a block of memory that big on any device.

The background image that you are setting is too large. Based on the memory allocation, it is equivalent to a 2048px by 2048px square image, which is bigger than any Android device screen that I am aware of.

You need to make this background image have a lower resolution, or employ other solutions for your background that avoid using a bitmap for a background image.

Comment: Even though i removed the background image, it still have same problems , the image i am setting for button is of 512 * 512 px is it right or i have to change it? if so to what resolution?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to commonsWare's answer:

If you believe that your image is properly sized, then you probably stored it in the wrong folder. Try `drawable-nodpi` if you don't want it to be scaled at all.

Or, for smaller devices, you may want to provide properly sized images in the related `drawable-**dpi` folders.

Comment: I have store , background image in drawable folder, and other images that are used for buttons are even stored in drawable folder, button images are 512 * 512px resolution

Comment: drawable folder (w/o any suffix) is not the same as drawable-nodpi.